# How to move newly exported files to new folders each time the are created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with the internet_stability library in python and I want to use it to, as the name implies test my internet stability and also speed.

The code I use works perfectly, but instead of using it only once, I would like to loop the code so that it can run throughout the day.

The problem I have is that library uses it's own exporting functions and that whenever you rerun the program it overwrites the old files.

So, I think a solution for this would be to create new folder every time it loops and put the exported files of that loop into the folders.

How would I go about doing this? The code I use is shown below.

```
import network_stability

net = network_stability.NetworkTest()

# Run connectivity test.

net.connection_test_interval(hours=0.1)
net.export_connection_results('connection.csv')
net.report_connection('connection.png')

# Run speed test.

net.speed_test_interval(minutes=10)
net.export_speed_results('speed.csv')
net.report_speed('speed.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import network_stability
import datetime

net = network_stability.NetworkTest()

# Run connectivity test.

net.connection_test_interval(hours=0.1)
net.export_connection_results(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")}_connection.csv')
net.report_connection(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")}_connection.png')

# Run speed test.

net.speed_test_interval(minutes=10)
net.export_speed_results(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")}_speed.csv')
net.report_speed(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")}_speed.png')
```

It will create files like this:

```
>>> f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")}_speed.png'                                                
'21_12_13-11_31_22_speed.png'
```

Because filenames are differents, it won t overwrite them. (Unless your run twice tests a second!)

If you want all you files has the same name in a run, do this:

```
import network_stability
import datetime

net = network_stability.NetworkTest()

date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")

# Run connectivity test.

net.connection_test_interval(hours=0.1)
net.export_connection_results(f'{date}_connection.csv')
net.report_connection(f'{date}_connection.png')

# Run speed test.

net.speed_test_interval(minutes=10)
net.export_speed_results(f'{date}_speed.csv')
net.report_speed(f'{date}_speed.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

For similar situations I use a simple workaround:

```
run_number = 0
save_name = "Connection" + str(run_number) 

net.export_speed_results(save_name + '.csv')
net.report_speed(save_name + '.png')

run_number += 1
```

Maybe that works for your problem as well?

Comment: Just to clarify, was save_number at the bottom meant to be run_number?

Comment: @Keenonthedaywalker: A, yes of course, my bad.

Comment: No problem, I figured that was what it was haha. I ran this code in a while loop but it still seems to overwrite the files, for example: connection0.csv remains that way and also speed 0.csv.

Comment: Nevermind I used user Vincent Bénet's method down below. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Understandable, it is quite more elaborate than my approach ;)

Comment: I still respect the simpler approach though :}